# How to join latest record for each foreign key without Inner select using group by and then on clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables **r_instance**(id as primary key,name,user_id,..etc) and **r_response**(id,comment,r_instance_id as Foreign key).
Each r_instance row have multiple r_response rows(say min of 3).

I want to get latest id and comment while joining r_response with r_instance.
But without using GROUP BY and then on clause on r_response as it is degrading query performance.So When query performance is considered using EXPLAIN the `type` column should not have **ALL** value.

My query is :

```
SELECT ri.id, ri.name, rr.id, rr.comment
FROM r_instance ri 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) maxResponseId, r_instance_id instanceId
      from r_response
      GROUP BY r_instance_id) lastRes ON lastRes.instanceId = ri.id
JOIN r_response rr ON rr.id = lastRes.maxResponseId
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use window function called `row_number()` MySQL 8.0+

```
SELECT * FROM
(
     SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r_instance_id ORDER BY id DESC) Sq
     from r_response
) a
INNER JOIN r_instance R ON R.id = a.r_instance_id
WHERE a.Sq = 1
```

Comment: Window functions don't come in until mysql 8+.

Comment: @P.Salmon.. Right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method:

```
SELECT ri.id, ri.name, rr.id, rr.comment
FROM r_instance ri JOIN
     JOIN r_response rr
     ON ri.id = rr.r_instance_id
WHERE rr.id = (SELECT MAX(rr2.id)
               FROM r_response rr2
               WHERE rr2.r_instance_id = rr.r_instance_id
              );
```

For performance, you want an index on `r_response(r_instance_id, id)`.

I should note that this does not always give the best performance.  It is another strategy for expressing the same logic, resulting in a different execution plan.  It might result in better performance.